# IPE Beam weight

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, beam

In civil engineering calculation I have seen weight of IPE 300 profile expressed in kN/m<sup>2</sup> unit.

IPE  300 0.42 kN/m<sup>2</sup>

I know IPE 300 is approximately 42.4 kg/m. How did they calculated that value expressed in kN/m<sup>2</sup>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density of structural steel is usually adopted as 7850 kg/m<sup>3</sup> (or thereabouts). According to [this source](http://www.b2bmetal.eu/i-sections-ipe-specification), the cross-sectional area of an IPE 300 section is 53.8 cm<sup>2</sup>. The linear mass of such a section is therefore 42.2 kg/m, which converts to a linear weight of 0.422 kN/m.

$$\begin{align}
m &= 42.2\ \text{kg/m} \\
w &= mg \\
&= 42.2 * 10 = 422\ \text{N/m} = 0.422\ \text{kN/m}
\end{align}$$

If you've seen anyone use 0.42 kN/m<sup>2</sup>, then you've seen someone doing it wrong and not paying attention to dimensional analysis.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing that was confusing me.Thank you.